# ¿Cómo evitar o eliminar el salto de línea que se crea automáticamente en batch?

Tags: batch, salto-de-linea

¿ Cómo evitar o eliminar el salto de línea que se crea automáticamente en batch al guardar texto ?

Quiero crear un archivo de texto plano con una sola línea de información pero sin que quede declarado posteriormente un salto de línea o retorno de carro.

Cuando introduzco el comando **echo 001>texto.txt** en **cmd.exe** se crea un archivo de texto con el texto "001" en la primera línea pero también queda definida la segunda línea (salto de línea) en dicho documento, como se muestra en la imagen que adjunto.

[image: salto de línea o retorno de carro en batch]

Lo que deseo es obtener un comando o método, que usando solamente batch me permita crear un archivo de texto plano con un texto dado pero solo en la primera linea, sin que quede declarado el salto de línea o retorno de carro en la segunda línea.

Answer (score 1):

El salto de línea lo escribe el `echo`.

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7105690/13419694) proponen usar una combinación de `echo` y `set /p` para quitarlo:

```
C:\> echo Hello World
Hello World

C:\> echo|set /p="Hello World"
Hello World
C:\>
```

---

Como alternativa podrías crear un programa en tu lenguaje de programación favorito que imprima todos los parámetros que reciba.

Un pequeño ejemplo en C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    foreach (var arg in args)
        Console.Write(arg + " ");
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##PcyxCsIwEMbx2TzF0SlF9AU6urgIgkMHcTjSWA/SHNylBZE@e0xU/K/3@87pzrH4nGelOMLlqclPnXEBVeEsPApO8DIbAyVNmMjBwjTACSlaTVJW1xugjNoWB7/u5Se6B9gFpR6B4tf8Re3AUTn4fS@UvK1sCw00bfdRq1lzzkcfAueeJQxv).